# Halting tar after locating entry or EOF in an actual tape archive

Tags: linux, restore, tar, tape

I've just been handed a pile of LTO-5s and a tape library, and the exciting task of extracting a subset of files.

Order of magnitude is **60 tapes** from said pile, **around 10,000 files of 70,000 per tape (in maybe half a dozen or a dozen asstd directories)** that I need to pull. Tape library is running **tar 1.23**

I do have pre-existing dumps of each tape's content as per `tar --list` so i'm happy to reconcile this with my list of files I need to pull so I can feed in a proper stream of records to grab, but

```
tar -xvf /dev/nst0 -b $file_to_pull
```

doesn't halt until i get to the end of the tape. Which makes sense - tar might be fed a wildcard pattern so it just goes to end of archive.

I guess I could solve this by just feeding in the directory glob and purging unwanted files once they're off tape, but I can't help but think there's got to be a way to halt tar at the EOF boundary and skip the purge step. Right? In all my hunting however, I've not found anything of that nature though..

So, questions:

- Is there a way to get tar (or heck, anything else) to pull just one file from wherever the tape head is, *and then stop*? Or to signal tar once it's gotten an EOF and stop?
- Alternately, am I mentally attacking this an odd way? Happy to take alt suggestions if anyone's got them.

Noting of course, this isn't a problem that's unsolvable right now, just my current options seem to be really awkward - this is the first time I've really had to deal with tape at this magnitude (and our other tapes are all LTFS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask tar to run an action every few blocks at what they call **checkpoints**. This action can test if the wanted file has been extracted and if so kill the tar. I tried it using a tar file and it seems to work ok.

Here's my example script to do my test, tarring /usr/bin and extracting usr/bin/bash into /tmp/usr/bin/bash. The default --checkpoint is 10 blocks.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<\! >/tmp/checkdone
#!/bin/bash
# env has TAR_CHECKPOINT TAR_ARCHIVE TAR_VERSION TAR_BLOCKING_FACTOR
# tar -C directory is NOT used for checkpoint action!
want=$1

if size=$(stat --printf='%s\n' "$want" 2>&1)
then if [ "$(</tmp/lastsize)" = "$size" -a -s /tmp/pid ]
    then  echo "same size $size. time to stop"
          ls -l "$want"
          >/tmp/lastsize
          kill -1 $(</tmp/pid)
    else  echo "partial size $size"
          echo "$size" >/tmp/lastsize
    fi
else echo -n "."
fi
!
chmod +x /tmp/checkdone
>/tmp/lastsize
>/tmp/pid

tar -cf /tmp/tar /usr/bin/ # create example tar file
# wanted file. must be in current dir
want=usr/bin/bash
cd /tmp || exit # dont use tar -C dir

tar -xvf /tmp/tar "$want" --checkpoint=10 --checkpoint-action=exec="/tmp/checkdone $want" &
echo $! >/tmp/pid
wait

rm /tmp/tar /tmp/pid /tmp/lastsize /tmp/checkdone
rm -fr /tmp/usr
```

Comment: Hm, cheers, I think this might be the closest I'll get (doing some tests now) without having to rewrite something low-level, but in the process of building the tape catalog (which I might do anyway for future reference) to get filesizes to know when to halt, I'm already having to do a single pass of the tape at which point I may as well just have done a full dump. Dammit, tar! *waves fist*

Comment: From what I remember of tape drives (10+ years ago) you might find the drive wont like stopping part way through a file, and will wind on to an inter-file gap anyway! Good luck, and my sympathies.

Comment: Ah well, it's tape, so the people who are asking me to treat it like a random access filesystem are getting an education in the process. I've just accepted that I might as well burn a couple of terabytes of disk so yeah, the drives are chattering away, and I've got a secondary process to prune unwanted files when the move from staging to live occurs. The things you do :P